# C Shared memory pointer mapping

Tags: c

I have a data structure as follows:

```
struct s1{
unsigned char* ptr;//points to an element in the shared memory
};

struct s1* s1Arr;
```

And I allocated a shared memory block and the pointer to it is:

```
unsigned char* shm_ptr.
```

I have an array of s1, with the same number of elements as there are elements in the shm_ptr array I allocated.

```
//point all the ptr elements of the struct to the shared memory elements(parallel array)
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
shm_ptr[i] = 99;
s1Arr[i].ptr = &shm_ptr[i];
printf("val=%d\n". *s1Arr[i].ptr);
}
```

When I go to print *s1Arr[i].ptr, it only prints i, where i is 0, 1...while it should be printing 99.
Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

I know the shared memory is working as I have tried to access it from another process.

```
void* allocArray_shared(int elementCount, int elementByteSize, int* shmid, key_t key)
{
    printf("allocshared errno=%d\n", errno);
    //size of entire array(cols*rows* byte size + row pointers)
    int array_size = elementByteSize * elementCount;


    //Allocate enough space for all elements + row pointers
    *shmid = shmget(key, array_size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    char * arr = (char*)shmat(*shmid, NULL, 0);
    if(!arr) return NULL;

    printf("allocshared end errno=%d\n", errno);

    //Return the pointer to the first row pointer
    return (void*)arr;
}
```

EDIT:
Found the issue..was allocating multiple shared memory segments with the same key and thus reads/writes were overlapping...ugh...

Comment: what did you expect it to show ?

Comment: I think you need to show the memory allocation code (shared and non-shared) and the printing code.  Without that, we're guessing about what you're doing.

Comment: I expect it to print 99, which is what i am setting the shared memory values to.

Comment: shm_ptr[i] = 99;
s1Arr[i].ptr = &shm_prt[i];
is it shm_ptr or shm_prt in second line?

Comment: Are there any other pieces to your code? ... It's kind of impossible for non-initialized memory to nicely count up from 0->COUNT.

Comment: Well..after I added the print statement it printed 99...but later on in the application..it prints wrong value..ugh probly something else going on..

Comment: Can you share the whole source on http://pastebin.com/ or similar?

Comment: shouldn't you allocate memory to unsigned char* shm_ptr

Comment: Sorry guys, full source is rather lengthy...all kinds of things going on...it seems the issue is not due to what I posted, but something else in the code....thanks for any help, just gotta debug some more for the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 99 displayed 5 times with this code. I think the only change is that I removed the keyword `struct` from the beginning of your struct array declaration (it was `struct s1 * s1Arr`).

**EDIT:** I put the `struct` keyword back in and got the same result, so I don't really know why my results are different than yours.

```
struct s1
{
    unsigned char * ptr;  //points to an element in the shared memory
};

s1 * s1Arr = new s1[5];
unsigned char * shm_ptr = new unsigned char[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   shm_ptr[i] = 99;
   s1Arr[i].ptr = &shm_ptr[i];
   cout << ((int)*s1Arr[i].ptr) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I found that works too...I was just being stupid and allocating multiple shared memory segments with the same key.....lol at me.